# Python help using for loop to change x

Tags: python, for-loop, raspberry-pi

First, today is the first time I have used Python. I used Perl 15 years ago, so very rusty but eager to learn. I'm trying to convert the following lines into a `for` loop, using `x` to increment ONrelay (so ONrelay0, ONrelay1, ONrelay3, and so on):

```
cpi6x.setbit(board1, cpi6x.ONrelay0)
time.sleep(.300)
cpi6x.setbit(board1, cpi6x.ONrelay1)
time.sleep(.300)
cpi6x.setbit(board1, cpi6x.ONrelay2)
time.sleep(.300)
cpi6x.setbit(board1, cpi6x.ONrelay3)
time.sleep(.300)
cpi6x.setbit(board1, cpi6x.ONrelay4)
```

I have tried the following, but not surprisingly it doesn't work.

```
for x in range(0, 5):
    cpi6x.setbit(board1, cpi6x.ONrelay%d) % (x)
    time.sleep(.300)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That won't work as `ONrelay` is not a string, but instance attributes, use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr) instead:

```
for i in range(5):
    obj = getattr(cpi6x, 'ONrelay{}'.format(i))
    cpi6x.setbit(board1, obj)
    time.sleep(.300)
```

Comment: or, with `%`-style formatting: `getattr(cpi6x, 'ONrelay%d' % i)`

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus .. correct...That will work too

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier and more Pythonic to put the relays in an array:

```
relays = [cpi6x.ONrelay0,
          cpi6x.ONrelay1,
          cpi6x.ONrelay2,
          cpi6x.ONrelay3,
          cpi6x.ONrelay4]

for relay in relays:
    cpi6x.setbit(board1, relay)
    time.sleep(.300)
```

You could also access the individual relays as `relays[x]` instead of separate variable names.